# Error de sintaxis al hacer un Left Join - Consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de hacer un Left Join pero cuando ingreso mi código me sale error de sintaxis y pero veo que mi código no esta mal alguien puede validar?

**Mi código MySQL**

```
SELECT * FROM 4am_comsysn.ageperso LEFT JOIN (SELECT 4am_traficon.ts_horas.coduser, 
            COUNT( DISTINCT 4am_traficon.ts_horas.codorden) AS orden, 
            COUNT( 4am_traficon.ts_horas.corre) AS core, 
            SUM( 4am_traficon.ts_horas.tothoras) AS horas, 4am_traficon.ts_horas.fecha 
        FROM 4am_traficon.ts_horas 
        GROUP BY 4am_traficon.ts_horas.coduser) 4am_traficon.ts_horas ON 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codper = 4am_traficon.ts_horas.coduser;
```

Adjunto captura del error

[image: Captura de imagen]

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el error?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nu636i @JYass

Comment: Creo que es el alias de la subconsulta podrías pobrar por fa? SELECT * FROM 4am_comsysn.ageperso LEFT JOIN (SELECT 4am_traficon.ts_horas.coduser, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT 4am_traficon.ts_horas.codorden) AS orden, 
   COUNT( 4am_traficon.ts_horas.corre) AS core, 
   SUM( 4am_traficon.ts_horas.tothoras) AS horas, 4am_traficon.ts_horas.fecha 
  FROM 4am_traficon.ts_horas 
  GROUP BY 4am_traficon.ts_horas.coduser) tt_ts_horas ON 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codper = tt_ts_horas.coduser;

Comment: @DrakoRod si funciono pero no me conto los datos ni sumo nada de la subconsulta mira http://prntscr.com/nu67ax

Comment: @DrakoRod le puse un en vez de LEFT un RIGHT y funciono

Comment: @CarlosVargas Dependerá de la posición de las tablas en la consulta, cuando pones LEFT, priorizará los registro de las izquierda aunque haya nulos en la tabla derecha, y el RIGHT priorizará los registros encontrados dentro de la tabla de la derecha. Eso ya depende de la estructura y registros que tengas. Te parece si coloco la respuesta con el RIGHT?

Comment: @DrakoRod si claro muchas gracias, soy un poco nuevo aún haciendo consultas de ese tipo pero ya voy aprendiendo

Comment: No te preocupes @CarlosVargas tu pregunta aquí estamos para ayudarnos Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es referente a la forma en la que colocaste el alias de la subconsulta:

```
SELECT * FROM 4am_comsysn.ageperso RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 4am_traficon.ts_horas.coduser, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT 4am_traficon.ts_horas.codorden) AS orden, 
            COUNT( 4am_traficon.ts_horas.corre) AS core, 
            SUM( 4am_traficon.ts_horas.tothoras) AS horas, 4am_traficon.ts_horas.fecha 
        FROM 4am_traficon.ts_horas 
        GROUP BY 4am_traficon.ts_horas.coduser) tt_ts_horas ON 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codper = tt_ts_horas.coduser;
```